# My bootstrap collapsing navbar not responding

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing around with Bootstrap 4 lately, and I have tried to make a collapsing navbar. I have copied the example from they're documentation, and tested it in the browser.

When I minimize the screen, the content DOES disappear, and the nav icon DOES appear, but when I click it, the nav does not open.

Do you know why?
Thanks.

The code:

```
  <nav id="myNav" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsing">
        &#9776;
    </button>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-xs-9 collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="collapsing">
            <li class="nav-item active pull-right">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item pull-right">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item pull-right">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">gallery</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item pull-right">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item pull-right">                                
                <a href="#"><img src="facebook.gif" id="facebook" alt="facebook icon"></a>  
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is due to the fact that the navbar requires `bootstrap.min.js` which in turn requires `jquery.js`.

You are missing one of those.